# How to build SonarLint source code using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, sonarlint-eclipse

I am trying to build sonar lint for eclipse for development purpose and adding a new language. I made some changes but I am not able to generate a zip file which I can locally install in eclipse as a plugin.

I have tried

`mvn clean package` : Not working
`clean install` : Not working
`mvn compile`       : Not working

I have even tried opening plugin.xml and clicked the `green play` button which showed at the right corner of the screen as written in github. But it still does not work.

I am not finding any documentation related to this, how can we generate plugin to install it in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have understood your question, you want to build sonarlint eclipse plugin source code using Maven. Here is the command.

```
mvn clean package
```

Once build is successful, go to the following directory.

org.sonarlint.eclipse.site\target

You will find the zip file of your plugin ie. **org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-4.2.0-SNAPSHOT.zip**

Comment: I know how to install it, but I am trying to add a new language support and I am trying to build the plugin from master.

Comment: Eclipse plugin support Java, Javascript, Python. Which new Language do you want to add ?

Comment: I would like to add support for Apex, I have done this in SonarQube for Intellij. But I am not able to generate plugin zip from eclipse

Comment: Can you add the Apex editor plugin in eclipse from this link. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/apex-editor-ls

Comment: Thats editor. That wont do live code review. And as far as editor is concerned I use Illuminated cloud. I am publishing code review for Apex for different IDEs, Intellij is done, and not I have to do it for eclipse.

Comment: Have you done this before? Building plugin via SonarLint Source from git?

Comment: Yes, I do use frequently in eclipse, but I did not use Apex, I used in Java.

Comment: Sambit, it is not about Apex or Java, I just want to build the SonarLint Source files using maven in eclipse. I have modified the Sonarlint files locally and want to generate plugin, which I can test in eclipse.

Comment: Do you want to build your source code with SonarQube lint or Do you want to build sonarLint source code with sonar lint ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193563/discussion-between-nagendra-singh-and-sambit).